XRDP won't start on Ubuntu 24.04
I just installed 24.04 Ubuntu on my Dell laptop, but I can't get xrdp to connect.  It is listening fine on port 3389, but when I try to connect with Windows Remote Desktop Connection, it looks like it tries to come up, then I get this iBus Notification on my Ubuntu desktop about Wayland, and enabling the Virtual Keyboard.  Is there a way to fix this either on the Ubuntu side or the Windows side?

Well, I fixed the part of the issue myself by creating a file called /etc/environment.d/ibus-custom.conf, and adding these two lines:
unset GTK_IM_MODULE
unset QT_IM_MODULE
Then I rebooted my Ubuntu server, and now I can get in with Remote Desktop Connection. Now I get the annoying popup at the top that says:
GNOME remote desktop handover daemon
This connection is insecure.
Do you want to continue with an insecure connection? To make it secure
set "use redirection server name:i:1" in the RDP config
file.  If anyone knows how to fix this, I would appreciate the help.

I fixed all of my problems with Noble Numbat now.
This popup would appear at the top of my connection window:


GNOME remote desktop handover daemon
This connection is insecure. Do you want to continue with an insecure connection? To make it secure set "use redirection server name:i:1" in the RDP config file.

That was fixed by simply changing my Default.rdp file on my Windows server. The parameter was already in there, but it was set to 0, so I changed it to a 1, rebooted my Windows PC, and now I connect to my Noble Numbat server without any annoying popups or errors.
For any of you who run into similar problems if you upgrade to Noble Numbat, I hope this information helps you.
